# How do you set the "Friendly" name for a Visual Basic 6 ActiveX CLSID

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6, activex, ocx, cab

I have an ActiveX control that I wrote in Visual Basic 6 several years ago.
It's an OCX loaded by a CAB file and used in Internet Explorer.

If you go to Tools|Manage add-ons in Internet Explorer I noticed the name is listed as 
`MyControlName.MyClassName`

I'm looking for a way to set the Friendly Name.

I know I can set this in the registry for the (Default) `REG_SZ` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{Class ID}`

What is the best way to do this during installation via the browser?

I tried to set the key in the inf but was unsuccessful, I'm guessing permissions.

Is there an event's that raised in the control when `regsvr32` is called on the OCX where I could do this? Or an interface I should be implementing?

Thanks,

Comment: do you have the sources of the OCX ? If you can recompile it, change the Project Name and Project description in the Project->Properties dialog as you require and compile it again

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile time property of the OCX file set in the [project options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716296%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) dialog box.

Comment: I'm looking for the friendly name, e.g. with spaces. Project Name only changes it to ProjectName.ClassName in Manage Add-Ons screen. And Project Description had no affect. Using HKLM,Software\Classes\CLSID\{ClassId},,,"My Friendly Name" works in the inf if I extract the cab to a folder and and right click install, but doesn't seem to work when installed from the browser via an object tag